# Call ink! smart contracts from hardware devices that use embedded rust

Tags: ink, smart-contract

What would be the best rust crate or c++ libraries to call ink! smart contracts from hardware devices that use embedded rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `subxt` (submit extrinsics to a substrate node via RPC using only Rust) There is some extended test that you can reuse to call contracts:
Have a look [HERE](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/9d0041b49dc3dd1810cb2b55c8b14c87435e2d5d/testing/integration-tests/src/full_client/frame/contracts.rs#L36)